# How can a dynamic local Swift Package import another local Swift Package in the same Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have an Xcode project with two local dynamic Packages `PackageA` and `PackageB`. How do i write the import in `package.swift` to import PackageA so i can use it in PackageB, and the Xcode project can use both since it imports `PackageB`?

[image]

```
let package = Package(
    name: "PackageB",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "PackageB",
            targets: ["PackageB"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "PackageB",
            dependencies: ["PackageA"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "PackageBTests",
            dependencies: ["PackageB"]),
    ]
)

let package = Package(
    name: "PackageA",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "PackageA",
            targets: ["PackageA"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "PackageA",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "PackageATests",
            dependencies: ["PackageA"]),
    ]
)
```

This does not work, `PackageB` cant seem to find `PackageA`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "dynamic". Is it the type of the library? If so, you did not specify a value for parameter `type` in static function `library(names:type:targets:)`, in which case SPM chooses one, and will likely choose "static".

Comment: If your package B "needs to use" package A, you don't "import" it in the Package Manifest, instead you need to define a dependency (package A) in the package (B), and then use it in the target. Is this what you want? You didn't specify a dependency. Note that you can define a dependency with a file path as parameter (or a URL): Package.Dependency as several static function overloads. Note also, you need a package manifest for each package – don't use the snippet where you have two packages.